# Is it possible to select specific regex capture groups to create columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark

I'm currently attempting to write a program in Python that reads syslogs and runs a load of regex in order to extract the data into columns in a dataframe, after which i can perform analysis on it.

this is a sample of the syslog file:

```
Feb  1 00:00:02 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=192.150.249.87 DST=11.11.11.84 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=12973 PROTO=TCP SPT=220 DPT=6129 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  
Feb  1 00:00:02 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=24.17.237.70 DST=11.11.11.95 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=27095 PROTO=TCP SPT=220 DPT=6129 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  
Feb  1 00:00:07 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=192.150.249.87 DST=11.11.11.85 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=13801 PROTO=TCP SPT=220 DPT=6129 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  
Feb  1 00:00:17 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=192.150.249.87 DST=11.11.11.87 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=15432 PROTO=TCP SPT=220 DPT=6129 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  
Feb  1 00:00:24 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=24.17.237.70 DST=11.11.11.100 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=31168 PROTO=TCP SPT=220 DPT=6129 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  
Feb  1 00:00:27 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=192.150.249.87 DST=11.11.11.89 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=17292 PROTO=TCP SPT=220 DPT=6129 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  
Feb  1 00:00:31 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=211.168.230.94 DST=11.11.11.70 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=7204 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=1208 DPT=135 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  
Feb  1 00:00:31 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=211.168.230.94 DST=11.11.11.72 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=7206 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=1210 DPT=135 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  
Feb  1 00:00:31 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=211.168.230.94 DST=11.11.11.64 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=7198 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=1202 DPT=135 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

So far i have achieved this in PySpark using this method to load the data file:

```
raw_data_files = glob.glob('*.log')
base_df = spark.read.text(raw_data_files)
```

And extracting the data into columns like this:

```
ts_pattern =r'((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Apr|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+(\d+)\s+((0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(\:)(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9])(\:)(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9])))'
mth_pattern = r'(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Apr|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec\s+\d+\s+)'
dy_pattern = r'\s+(\d+)\s+'
tme_pattern = r'(([01]?\d|2[0-3]|24(?=:00?:00?$)):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d))'
src_pattern = r'((\sSRC.*?=)([0-9a-f\.]*))'
dst_pattern = r'((\sDST.*?=)([0-9a-f\.]*))'
dvc_pattern = r'((([01]?\d|2[0-3]|24(?=:00?:00?$)):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d))\s)(\S+)'
svc_pattern = r'((([01]?\d|2[0-3]|24(?=:00?:00?$)):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d))\s)(\S+)\s((?:(?!:).)*)'
ufw_pattern = r'(\bUFW\s\b)([^]\s]+)'
sts_pattern = r'((?<=stats:\s).*)'
in_pattern = r'((\bIN=\b)([^\s]+))'
physin_pattern = r'((\bPHYSIN=\b)([^\s]+))'
out_pattern = r'((\bOUT=\b)([^\s]+))'
physout_pattern = r'((\bPHYSOUT=\b)([^\s]+))'
mac_pattern = r'((\bMAC=\b)([^\s]+))'
len_pattern = r'((\bLEN=\b)([^\s]+))'
tos_pattern = r'((\bTOS=\b)([^\s]+))'
prec_pattern = r'((\bPREC=\b)([^\s]+))'
ttl_pattern = r'((\bTTL=\b)([^\s]+))'
id_pattern = r'((\bID=\b)([^\s]+))'
flag_pattern = r'(\b\sCE|DF|MF\s\b)'
prtc_pattern = r'((\bPROTO=\b)([^\s]+))'
spt_pattern = r'((\bSPT=\b)([^\s]+))'
dpt_pattern = r'((\bDPT=\b)([^\s]+))'
recseq_pattern = r'((\bSEQ=\b)([^\s]+))'
ackseq_pattern = r'((\bSEQ=\b)([^\s]+))'
win_pattern = r'((\bWINDOW=\b)([^\s]+))'
res_pattern = r'((\bRES=\b)([^\s]+))'
synurgp_pattern = r'((\bSYN\sURGP=\b)([^\s]+))'
status_pattern = r'((\bkernel:\s\b)(((eth|br|dev|Ker).*)))'

    # Combined regex
logs_df = base_df.select(regexp_extract('value', mth_pattern, 1).alias('month'),
                         regexp_extract('value', dy_pattern, 1).alias('day'),
                         regexp_extract('value', tme_pattern, 1).alias('time'),
                         regexp_extract('value', src_pattern, 3).alias('source'),
                         regexp_extract('value', dst_pattern, 3).alias('destination'),
                         regexp_extract('value', dvc_pattern, 6).alias('device'),
                         regexp_extract('value', svc_pattern, 7).alias('service'),
                         regexp_extract('value', ufw_pattern, 2).alias('ufw rule'),
                         regexp_extract('value', sts_pattern, 1).alias('stats event'),
                         regexp_extract('value', status_pattern, 3).alias('status event'),
                         regexp_extract('value', in_pattern, 3).alias('input'),
                         regexp_extract('value', physin_pattern, 3).alias('physinput'),
                         regexp_extract('value', out_pattern, 3).alias('output'),
                         regexp_extract('value', physout_pattern, 3).alias('physout'),
                         regexp_extract('value', mac_pattern, 3).alias('mac address'),
                         regexp_extract('value', len_pattern, 3).cast('integer').alias('length'),
                         regexp_extract('value', tos_pattern, 3).alias('typeofservice'),
                         regexp_extract('value', prec_pattern, 3).alias('precedence'),
                         regexp_extract('value', ttl_pattern, 3).cast('integer').alias('timetolive'),
                         regexp_extract('value', id_pattern, 3).cast('integer').alias('id'),
                         regexp_extract('value', flag_pattern, 1).alias('flag'),
                         regexp_extract('value', prtc_pattern, 3).alias('protocol'),
                         regexp_extract('value', spt_pattern, 3).cast('integer').alias('sourceport'),
                         regexp_extract('value', dpt_pattern, 3).cast('integer').alias('destinationport'),
                         regexp_extract('value', recseq_pattern, 3).cast('integer').alias('recseqnumber'),
                         regexp_extract('value', ackseq_pattern, 3).cast('integer').alias('ackseqnumber'),
                         regexp_extract('value', win_pattern, 3).cast('integer').alias('window'),
                         regexp_extract('value', res_pattern, 3).alias('reserved'),
                         regexp_extract('value', synurgp_pattern, 3).cast('integer').alias('synurgp'))
```

printed dataframe:

```
+-----+---+--------+--------------+------------+------+-------+--------+-----------+------------+-----+---------+------+-------+-----------+------+-------------+----------+----------+-----+----+--------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+------+--------+-------+
|month|day|    time|        source| destination|device|service|ufw rule|stats event|status event|input|physinput|output|physout|mac address|length|typeofservice|precedence|timetolive|   id|flag|protocol|sourceport|destinationport|recseqnumber|ackseqnumber|window|reserved|synurgp|
+-----+---+--------+--------------+------------+------+-------+--------+-----------+------------+-----+---------+------+-------+-----------+------+-------------+----------+----------+-----+----+--------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+------+--------+-------+
|  Feb|  1|00:00:02|192.150.249.87| 11.11.11.84|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    40|         0x00|      0x00|       110|12973|    |     TCP|       220|           6129|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:02|  24.17.237.70| 11.11.11.95|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    40|         0x00|      0x00|       113|27095|    |     TCP|       220|           6129|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:07|192.150.249.87| 11.11.11.85|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    40|         0x00|      0x00|       110|13801|    |     TCP|       220|           6129|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:17|192.150.249.87| 11.11.11.87|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    40|         0x00|      0x00|       110|15432|    |     TCP|       220|           6129|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:24|  24.17.237.70|11.11.11.100|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    40|         0x00|      0x00|       113|31168|    |     TCP|       220|           6129|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:27|192.150.249.87| 11.11.11.89|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    40|         0x00|      0x00|       110|17292|    |     TCP|       220|           6129|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:31|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.70|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7204|  DF|     TCP|      1208|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:31|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.72|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7206|  DF|     TCP|      1210|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:31|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.64|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7198|  DF|     TCP|      1202|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:32|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.69|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7203|  DF|     TCP|      1207|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:32|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.73|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7207|  DF|     TCP|      1211|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:32|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.75|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7209|  DF|     TCP|      1213|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:32|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.80|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7214|  DF|     TCP|      1218|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:32|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.67|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7201|  DF|     TCP|      1205|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:32|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.71|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7205|  DF|     TCP|      1209|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:32|192.150.249.87| 11.11.11.90|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    40|         0x00|      0x00|       110|18107|    |     TCP|       220|           6129|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:32|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.70|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7235|  DF|     TCP|      1208|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:32|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.72|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7237|  DF|     TCP|      1210|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:32|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.69|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7234|  DF|     TCP|      1207|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
|  Feb|  1|00:00:32|211.168.230.94| 11.11.11.80|bridge| kernel|        |           |            |  br0|     eth0|   br0|   eth1|           |    48|         0x00|      0x00|       110| 7233|  DF|     TCP|      1218|            135|        null|        null| 16384|    0x00|      0|
+-----+---+--------+--------------+------------+------+-------+--------+-----------+------------+-----+---------+------+-------+-----------+------+-------------+----------+----------+-----+----+--------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+------+--------+-------+
```

This method works very well and i'm happy with the result, however, i would like to make this work without using Apache Spark if possible. It's a great tool but I think it may be too much for this use case.

I've tried to achieve similar results using Pandas by reading the file as fwf, which isn't ideal as it splits it into odd columns due to the log format. This wouldn't be a problem if i could extract data from the dataframe using specific regex groups like in PySpark. I cannot find anyway to do this in Pandas. Or anyway to compile all the regex into one command and create columns that way using the specified groups.

I have tried combining all columns in the Pandas dataframe into 1, and then extracting data into new columns using str.extract. But this method only works if my regex have 1 capture group, which is not possible to achieve and still get relevant results.

I have also tried to combine all my regex patterns into one, and extracting data that way, as shown below:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np

# define regex patterns
mth = r'(?P<month>Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Apr|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec\s+\d+\s+)'
dy = r'\s+(?P<day>\d+)\s+'
tme = r'(?P<time>([01]?\d|2[0-3]|24(?=:00?:00?$)):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d))'
src = r'\sSRC.*?=?(?P<source>[0-9a-f\.]*)'
dst = r'\sDST.*?=(?P<destination>[0-9a-f\.]*)'

# import all files 
data = pd.read_fwf('/home/fred/Documents/PythonProjects/LogFileReader/SotM30-anton.log', header=None)
all_re = re.compile('({0}{1}{2}{3}{4})'.format(mth, dy, tme, src, dst))
# parse to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# format to single column
df = df.rename(columns={0 : 'c1', 1 : 'c2', 2 : 'c3', 3 : 'c4', 4 : 'c5'})
cols = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']
df['combined'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
print(df)
```

result of print(df):

```
         c1  c2        c3      c4       c5                                                  5                       combined
0       Feb   1  00:00:02  bridge  kernel:  INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOU...  Feb 1 00:00:02 bridge kernel:
1       Feb   1  00:00:02  bridge  kernel:  INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOU...  Feb 1 00:00:02 bridge kernel:
2       Feb   1  00:00:07  bridge  kernel:  INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOU...  Feb 1 00:00:07 bridge kernel:
3       Feb   1  00:00:17  bridge  kernel:  INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOU...  Feb 1 00:00:17 bridge kernel:
4       Feb   1  00:00:24  bridge  kernel:  INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOU...  Feb 1 00:00:24 bridge kernel:
...     ...  ..       ...     ...      ...                                                ...                            ...
307519  Feb   7  14:35:06  bridge  kernel:  OUTG CONN TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth1 OUT=br0 PHYS...  Feb 7 14:35:06 bridge kernel:
307520  Feb   7  14:36:12  bridge  kernel:  INBOUND UDP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOU...  Feb 7 14:36:12 bridge kernel:
307521  Feb   7  14:39:04  bridge  kernel:  INBOUND UDP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOU...  Feb 7 14:39:04 bridge kernel:
307522  Feb   7  14:39:11  bridge  kernel:  INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 PHYSOU...  Feb 7 14:39:11 bridge kernel:
307523  Feb   7  14:40:06  bridge  kernel:  OUTG CONN TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth1 OUT=br0 PHYS...  Feb 7 14:40:06 bridge kernel:
```

```
new_df = df[['combined']].copy()
x = new_df['combined'].str.extract(all_re, expand=True)
print(x)
```

But this just results in a dataframe filled with NaN (result of print(x)):

```
          0 month  day time    4    5    6 source destination
0       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN         NaN
1       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN         NaN
2       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN         NaN
3       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN         NaN
4       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN         NaN
...     ...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...    ...         ...
307519  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN         NaN
307520  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN         NaN
307521  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN         NaN
307522  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN         NaN
307523  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN         NaN
```

It does seem to be getting the capture group names and using them as column headers, but something is going wrong as it isn't getting any values.

So to summarize, i want to extract data from syslog files using regular expressions, and parse the results into columns in a dataframe, so as to do analytics on the data. I can do this using Apache Spark, but would prefer not to. I would like to use Pandas, but do not know how to specify regex capture groups and compile them all together as in Apache Spark. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group dictionaries in the standard re library might be of use to you:
[groupdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict)

Once you have your dictionary of matches you should be able to iterate through them to build a table.

See also the tokenizer example in the re docs:
[Writing a Tokenizer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer)

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This method seems like it could be effective. Thank you, I will give it a go.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I read the log file line by line, and ran the regex over each in a for loop, and stored the correct capture group in a list, then built a dataframe from the resulting lists.

Comment: Nice one. Glad I could be of some help.